# Nuxt 2 module parse failing, unexpected token

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, babeljs

I'm trying to use transformers.js in my Nuxt 2 app but it keeps giving me errors. I have tried to add some babel configs in nuxt.config.js but didn't fix it.

Errors that I'm getting.:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/processors.js 179:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (179:46)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         this.image_std = this.config.image_std;
| 
>         this.resample = this.config.resample ?? 2; // 2 => bilinear
|         this.do_rescale = this.config.do_rescale ?? true;
|         this.rescale_factor = this.config.rescale_factor ?? (1 / 255);
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/tokenizers.js 189:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (189:46)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|         /** @type {boolean} Whether to fuse unknown tokens when encoding. Defaults to false. */
>         this.fuse_unk = this.config.fuse_unk ?? false;
|     }
| 
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/models.js 265:49
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (265:49)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|     // Prepare attention mask
>     let pad_token_id = self.config.pad_token_id ?? null;
|     let eos_token_id = self.config.eos_token_id ?? null;
|     if (isIntegralNumber(eos_token_id)) {
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/utils/hub.js 39:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (39:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|      * Mapping from file extensions to MIME types.
|      */
>     _CONTENT_TYPE_MAP = {
|         'txt': 'text/plain',
|         'html': 'text/html',
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/env.js 42:56
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (42:56)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| const __dirname = RUNNING_LOCALLY
>     ? path.dirname(path.dirname(url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)))
|     : './';
| 
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/pipelines.js 482:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (482:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| export class Text2TextGenerationPipeline extends Pipeline {
>     _key = null;
| 
|     /**
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/utils/tensor.js 568:43
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (568:43)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|     // Input image dimensions
>     const in_channels = input.dims.at(-3) ?? 1;
|     const in_height = input.dims.at(-2);
|     const in_width = input.dims.at(-1);
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/utils/image.js 72:22
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (72:22)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|      * Mapping from file extensions to MIME types.
|      */
>     _CONTENT_TYPE_MAP = {
|         'png': 'image/png',
|         'jpg': 'image/jpeg',
ERROR in ./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/configs.js 85:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (85:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     } = {}) {
| 
>         let data = config ?? await loadConfig(pretrained_model_name_or_path, {
|             progress_callback,
|             config,
```

It looks like problem is caused by the transpiler and I have tried to install and add these babel plugins to see if ı can get rid of nullish coalescing but no luck. Is there anything I can try at this point?

```
    build: {
        babel: {
            plugins: [
                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }],
                '@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator',
            ],
        },
    },
```